Is it haram, as a recruiter to look candidate for gambling company?
I am a recruiter in an IT / Headhunter company. Sometimes I need to look for candidates for our clients from the Gambling/Casino industry. Is it okay for me to continue the job or is it haram?
Thank you for your answers, it would be very helpful for me.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your question, do you think that gambling is halal and something which one should support?
